# Angular V11 to V12 : ERROR in Cannot resolve type entity i11.DynamicViewModule to symbol

Tags: compiler-errors, upgrade, angular11, angular12

On updating Angular from V11 to V12 I am getting above error on ng serve.
I do not have any DynamicViewModule in my app. not sure why the error is coming, did not get anything online. Not sure what exactly am I missing.

Any help would be appreciated.
Below is my package.json

```
  "name": "peer-review-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^12.2.15",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.2.15",
    "@angular/common": "^12.2.15",
    "@angular/compiler": "^12.2.15",
    "@angular/core": "^12.2.15",
    "@angular/forms": "^12.2.15",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/material": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^11.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^12.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^12.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^12.2.15",
    "@angular/router": "^12.2.15",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.0.1",
    "@ciri/ngx-countdown": "^1.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^2.0.2",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.10.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.36",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fullcalendar/angular": "^5.3.1",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.3.2",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.3.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^11.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/schematics": "^2.0.0-alpha.1",
    "@ngneat/hot-toast": "^4.1.0",
    "@ngneat/overview": "^1.0.0",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^26.1.0",
    "ag-grid-community": "^26.1.0",
    "ag-grid-enterprise": "^26.1.0",
    "angular-highcharts": "8.0.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "highcharts": "6.0.6",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ng-circle-progress": "^1.5.1",
    "ng-mat-search-bar": "^10.0.0-beta.3",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.2.14",
    "ng2-search-filter": "^0.5.1",
    "ngx-extended-pdf-viewer": "^4.1.0",
    "ngx-malihu-scrollbar": "^9.0.0",
    "primeicons": "2.0.0",
    "primeng": "^12.2.3",
    "rxjs": "^7.5.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "tslib": "^2.3.1",
    "xlsx": "^0.16.5",
    "zone.js": "0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.800.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.2.15",
    "@angular/language-service": "8.2.7",
    "@types/highcharts": "5.0.20",
    "@types/jasmine": "3.4.4",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "5.0.1",
    "highcharts": "6.0.6",
    "jasmine-core": "3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "5.15.0",
    "typescript": "4.2.3"
  }
}
```

Please let me know if anything else is needed from my side.
Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score -2):

Try cleaning your `node_modules` folder and doing an `npm i`.